# Loop Through each Cells in another workbook with a For Each Loop

Tags: vba, excel

quick question about the For Each In expression:
I use this line for all the rows in the same file, but different sheet:

```
For Each c In tarRng
        count = count + 1
        Debug.Print "c.Value: "; c.Value
        Debug.Print "cAdd: "; c.Address
        Debug.Print "count"; count
Next
```

tarRng is defined as all rows of the B column which works perfect, it cycles through all rows and outputs the value in the row and the address of each value in the debug screen. The count is there for a later function which I just left out here.

Now the question: I would like to get the B column of a different Workbook in the same folder, but when I define it like this (here fixed range since I just wanted to test it).

```
For Each c In Workbooks("Nvm_Configuration_ASW.xlsm").Worksheets("Tabelle2").Range("B3:B271")
```

It just shows the count once with the value 1 and doesn't even output c.Value or c.Address. I am sure the expression for the file and sheet are right since I tried it with the same file I am in as the filename and it worked.

Thanks,
Mathias

Comment: Did you open workbook in question (Nvm_Configuration_ASW)?

Comment: Yeah I have to file open, should I close it?

Comment: It should stay opened, but in the same Excel instance.

Comment: What is value for `Workbooks("Nvm_Configuration_ASW.xlsm").Worksheets("Tabelle2").Range("B3:B271")` in watch window? Is it `Nothing`?

Comment: Sry I haven't used the watch window before, but I just added the Workbooks("Nvm_Configuration_ASW.xlsm").Worksheets("Tabelle2").Range("B3:B271")  to it and ran the macro and it says "outside of context" would be the english translation since I use german excel, type is empty. I also checked it for tarRng and there its the same "outside of context" and type is variant/empty for that one.

Comment: Oh I am sorry, for tarRng it says: "Out of context" and Type is "Range", I forgot to add it to the watch window.

Comment: Can you include line where you define `tarRng`?

Comment: Set tws = Workbooks("compws.xlsm").Worksheets("Tabelle1")
    LastrowTar = tws.Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    Set tarRng = tws.Range("B3:B" & LastrowTar)     
compws.xlsm is the file where I am currently working in and it works fine.
I don't know how to format the comment here Ctrl + K doesn't work here like in the post editor sry for formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the workbook is not opened, you have to open it with `Workbooks.Open()`:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim wks As Workbook

    Set wks = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Nvm_Configuration_ASW.xlsm")        
    For Each myCell In wks.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A5")
        Debug.Print myCell
    Next        

End Sub
```

If it is opened, your code should be working, **but** it should be opened in the same Excel Instance.

By default it would be opened in the same instance, unless you do not make some additional tricks:

- press <kbd>Alt</kbd> when openning it for Excel 2017
- openning an Excel file and closing it from the small inner cross for Excel 2013 and earlier.

Comment: Ok so I added that, closed the file, then ran the macro. It opens the file, but still only shows count 1. It doesn't even print the Debug.Print c. I use excel 2013 if that helps.

Comment: @M.Schedl - can you delete all the worksheets and leave only one? Including the hidden ones.

Comment: Your code seems to work thought (When I just copy and pasted it), so I have to just change mine accordingly, thanks.

Comment: I changed my code now accordingly, it seems it didn't like that I just used c instead of a longer name for the For Each In. It works now thank you for the help!